# Open new Apple Pages files in an old computer

Tags: macos, mac, iwork-pages

I have and old iMac 24 has OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 and Pages 5.5.3. I need to open some Apple Pages files created in a new Mac computer. The new computer has the last version of Mac OS MacOS Sierra and the last Pages. I am not sure about the versions.

I cannot update the iMac 24 to OS Sierra. If I try in the App Store it says: "This version of macOS 10.12.2 cannot be installed on this computer". I suppose the computer is too old.

Is there any way I can open the Apple Pages files in the old iMac 24?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could open the old files if I uploaded them to iCloud. iCloud always has the last version of Pages and Numbers. That method works well.